# Shaped drawable with selectableItemBackground as background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-drawable, android-selector

I have couple buttons that I need an oval shaped border.

So i have this in a capsule_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="9999dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="@color/border_gray" />
</shape>
```

And I would use `android:background="@drawable/capsule_border.xml` where I need it.

Now, I would like to have a button to have this oval shaped border, but also a `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"` for the visual feedback.

I tried to use a parent layout with the selectableItembackground and button with capsule_border. But it seems that the clickable area that gets highlighted is the whole square. Instead of only the area within the capsule border.

[image]

Is there someway that I can make it so that the selectableItemBackground does not highly the whole rectangle of the view, but only within the border that i draw?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Having **round_corners.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

And **my_ripple.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_corners" />
</ripple>
```

And button:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/my_ripple"
    ... />
```

Will result in this:

[image]

See [this](http://michaelevans.org/blog/2015/05/07/android-ripples-with-rounded-corners/) article.

Comment: It's really nice. Would have been better if there is a <21 api level version.

Comment: Bless You for this!

Comment: Finally I understand that ripple drawable thing

Answer (score 16):

I have a simpler version of the first answer:

```xml
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?colorControlHighlight"> <!-- default ripple color -->

    <item>
        <!-- the background shape when it's not being clicked -->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="32dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

---

Just apply it as background but remember to **REMOVE THE SHADOW** if it applys to `Button`:

`style="?borderlessButtonStyle"`

Good luck!

---

[image]

Comment: What is the minimum android version for this solution?

Comment: @Zhen Liu I don't see any API Level requirement wanring, it's good for all version I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simpler solution now in 2020 (API >= 21 because we're using the `?attr` syntax) :

```xml
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?colorControlHighlight">
    <!--  the ripple's color (1) -->

    <!--  no `id` so our <shape> will be drawn and not just used as mask -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="9dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

> `(1)` If you don't override `colorControlHighlight` in your theme, the ripple's color will be Android's default. If you *do* override it but still want to use Android's default use `?android:colorControlHighlight` instead

Comment: This approach works, but it has the problem that it always draws a background color (white in this case) when the item is not clicked. This causes overdraw. On the other hand, using a mask we can have a default transparent background and avoid that overdraw.

Comment: @flaw just delete solid line and use backgroundTint. 

This should be the #1 answer In 2021 because of the new system ripple effect

Comment: Better solution for 2021